# How to turn off App notification from inside the app

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-preferences

How do you turn off Notification programmatically from a settings options inside an app?

The approach of creating the Notification channel inside an if statement in a Preference change listener seems to be doing the job. I'm concerned that the I'm creating multiple Notification channels now.

Preference.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory
    app:key="notification_category"
    app:title="Notification"
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
         app:key="notification_state"
         app:title="Enable notification message"/>
</PrefenceCategory>
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
boolean mNotificationState;
Notification mNotification;

SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Create notification object.
    mNotification = Notification(this);

    // Prefernce Listener
    listner = (sharedPrefences, s) -> {
        mNotificationState = SharedPreferences.getBoolean("notification_state", true);
    if(mNotificationState) {
        // concerned that a memory leak migh occur.
        notification.createNotificationChannel();
    } else {
        notification.getNotificationManager().cancelAll();
    }
}

/**
 * registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
 */
@Override
public void onResume() {   
    super.onResume();
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
} 

/*
 * unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext()).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    super.onDestroy(); 
}
```

**Notification.class**, contains a NotificationChannel method, notfication method, and getNotificationManager (gettter).

```
private Context mContext;

// Constructor
public Notification(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

// Notification channel. 
public void createNotificationChannel() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "notification_ID";
        String description = "My Notificatin";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    }
    // Set NotificationChannel ch = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_ID, name, importance);
    ch.setDescription(description);

    // Register the channel.
    notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(ch);
}

public NotificationManager getNotificationManager() {
    return notificationManager;
}
```

Comment: How about saving the toggle value is SharedPreferencs and when the notification receives then show it to the user according to the toggle value saved

Comment: Do you use FCM?

Comment: Im not using FCM, notification are coming from the app not a server.

Comment: Do you use java or kotlin?

Comment: @NatigBabayev I'm using Java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the notif not push messages type, then :

1. Disable all currently shown notification  and toggle off sharedPrefs value

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->

        if (isChecked) {

            mSharedPrefs.save(MySharedPrefs.NOTIFICATION_ENABLED, true)

        } else {

            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).cancelAll()

            mSharedPrefs.save(MySharedPrefs.NOTIFICATION_ENABLED, false)

        }

    }
```

2. Check `MySharedPrefs.NOTIFICATION_ENABLED` state at part of the code where you actually build and show the notification(eg. BroadcastReceiver)

```
if (mSharedPrefs.getValueBoolean(MySharedPrefs.NOTIFICATION_ENABLED)) {
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.CHANNEL_ID)

     NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
}
```

Comment: I created my code based on your suggestion, could you please have a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Android does not have an API to disable Notifications.
However, you can delete the GCM/FCM token from server, thus achieving the objective.

Comment: how do they accomplish in the stack overflow app then?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user's choice in shared preferences. Then check for its value and show the notification if its value is true else don't show it.